# Como usar os atributos da Bass_FX.dll?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, bass

Seguinte. Eu estava utilizando a bass.dll sem qualquer problema. Porém quando tento utilizar os atributos da bass_fx.dll, a bass não reconhece. 
Eu realizei a instalação das duas dlls da seguinte maneira.

1- Copiei as dlls para a pasta do exe.

2- Adicionei ao projeto as respectivas units devidamente atualizadas, recém baixadas do site da un4seen.

Segue o código:

```
program BassFXTest;

uses
    Vcl.Forms,
    Vcl.Dialogs,
    SysUtils,
    Variants,
    bass in 'Bass\bass.pas',
    bass_fx in 'Bass\bass_fx.pas';

var
    Form : TForm;
    Channel : HChannel;
    Sample : HSample;
    Filename : PChar;

begin
    Application.Initialize;
    filename := PChar('sample.ogg');
    Application.MainFormOnTaskBar := true;
    Application.CreateForm(TForm, Form);
    if not Bass_Init(-1, 44100, 0, 0, nil) then
        ShowMessage('Error initing (' + IntToStr(Bass_ErrorGetCode) + ').');
    Sample := Bass_SampleLoad(false, filename, 0, 0, 1000, BASS_UNICODE);
    if Sample = 0 then
        ShowMessage('Error loading sample (' + IntToStr(Bass_ErrorGetCode) + ').');
    Channel := Bass_SampleGetChannel(Sample, false);
    if Channel = 0 then
        ShowMessage('Error creating Channel (' + IntToStr(Bass_ErrorGetCode) + ').');
    if not BASS_ChannelSetAttribute(Channel, BASS_ATTRIB_VOL, 1) then
        ShowMessage('Error VOL (' + IntToStr(Bass_ErrorGetCode) + ').');
    if not BASS_ChannelSetAttribute(Channel, BASS_ATTRIB_TEMPO_PITCH, 3) then
        ShowMessage('Error PITCH (' + IntToStr(Bass_ErrorGetCode) + ').');
    if not BASS_ChannelPlay(Channel, True) then
        ShowMessage('Error Playing Channel (' + IntToStr(Bass_ErrorGetCode) + ').');
    Application.Run;

end.
```

O código acima reproduz a amostra, mas não reconhece o atributo `BASS_ATTRIB_TEMPO_PITCH` ele só mostra a mensagem "Error PITCH (19)."; erro que segundo a documentação da bass significa que o atributo não existe. Mas de acordo com a documentação da bass_fx, esse atributo está correto. Onde pode estar o erro? Será que eu estou instalando a bass_fx de maneira errada?

Answer (score 2):

Observe que o atributo `BASS_ATTRIB_TEMPO_PITCH` só é suportado por *tempo streams*, criados com `BASS_FX_TempoCreate`.

```
// criar um "canal de decodificação" de um arquivo
decoder:=BASS_StreamCreateFile(FALSE, filename, 0, 0, BASS_STREAM_DECODE OR BASS_UNICODE); 
// criar um tempo stream para ele
tempostream:=BASS_FX_TempoCreate(decoder, BASS_FX_FREESOURCE); 
// definir o campo
BASS_ChannelSetAttribute(tempostream, BASS_ATTRIB_TEMPO_PITCH, pitch); 
// reproduz
BASS_ChannelPlay(tempostream, FALSE);
```

Comment: `tempostream, decoder : HStream`?

Comment: O programa [aqui](http://pastebin.com/aHWq2Fgj), lança um "Application Error". Se eu executar sem a linha `tempostream := BASS_FX_TempoCreate(decoder, BASS_FX_FREESOURCE);` ele roda, mas entra nas minhas exceções.